# How to use variables in string manipulations? aka how to refer to variables in other ways

Tags: string, batch-file

I have a batch file that helps me with string manipulation. It works as a plugin/function. The problem is, I don't know how do I use variables in string manipulation.

Here is the code that i have problem with:

```
set result=%_unstring:%_charstoreplace%=%_replacementchars%
```

*The variables `_unstring`, `_charstoreplace` and `_replacementchars` are all parameters.*

How do I use variables while manipulating `%_unstring%`?

Comment: Instead of entering into conversations after people have provided an answer for you, why not provide the exact code that is giving you an issue, and ask a specific question. As it stands your question is not representative of a reproducible problem, unclear and too difficult for us to help you with in a succinct manner. Please use the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49609311/edit), to update your question accordingly.

Comment: Just use `set result=!_unstring:%_charstoreplace%=%_replacementchars%!` and put a `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning. This method is fully explained at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) (although the topic is different).

Comment: But why after this command i do `echo %result%` and it outputs `ECHO is off.`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET "unstring=some string containing stuff"
SET "charstoreplace=ing cont"
SET "replacementchars=with this"

CALL SET "result=%%unstring:%charstoreplace%=%replacementchars%%%"
SET result
```

is probably the easiest. It relies on the parsing method used by batch.

Comment: It works but it only prints it out. like `result=Hi world` and it does not store it in the result variable. Also i would like it to not go one line down after executing. Any ideas?

Comment: @DatProgrammer - the result is stored in the variable `%result%`. The last `set` was used instead of `echo` to display the variable.